# Magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2

I want to develop a custom theme for Magento 2, but I can't find the default blank theme of Magento. The folder "/app/design/frontend/Magento" is empty. Shouldn't there be a "blank" directory? Can't find all the default templates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you downloaded and install Magento2 version from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download. 
You can find it in `<magento_dir>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/`

Comment: Yes I did it that way. Found it, thanks! Is there a reason why the theme in the git repository is at another location than in the zip-archive of magento?

Comment: hi @DominikBarann did you able to create your new custom theme??

Comment: It's still in production...

Answer (score 3):

To answer your comment about why the folder location of the themes differ, I will reference a post I found.

```
When installing via Composer (as recommended for production sites or anyone else 
wanting stability), Composer puts it under the vendor directory. This is standard 
Composer behavior.

So "vendor/Magento/theme-frontend-blank" is the root directory of the Composer package 
holding the blank theme. Magento will find the theme over in that directory as well. 
(This is one of the reasons there is a "registration.php" file in themes (and modules) 
now. It tells Magento where the theme sits on disk.)

So while developing a theme, or if theme is for a local project (not intended to be 
used across multiple projects), you put it under app/design. If you decide to sell it on 
Magento Marketplace for example, there are instructions to bundle it (basically ZIP the 
directory) and upload to the Marketplace. Other users that download it will have it put in 
their 'vendor' directory automatically by Composer. The 'vendor' directory holds all code 
 you did not write.
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2577

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 stable version 2 theme are :

```
1. <magento_dir>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma

2 .<magento_dir>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank
```

Answer (score 1):

if you using release version, you can find blank theme here: **vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank**

Answer (score 1):

For Magento2 stable version:
All modules and theme related folder are kept in `<magento_install_root>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/`

Thanks.